# Will my sins not be forgiven if I told people about it?

Tags: sin, tawba

I committed a sin and then I told others about it because I wanted their opinions. But then I read a statement saying that Allah forgives all sins except those who sin openly or tell others about them. Does that mean that I will not be forgiven if I repent, both from committing the sin and then telling others about it?

Comment: here i think the same question may help you https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/51688/30088

Comment: It is rather disliked to post duplicate questions in the SE-Network! For further information on our site and model take the [tour] and check our [help].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true that Allah forgives all sins except those who expose them?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51686/is-it-true-that-allah-forgives-all-sins-except-those-who-expose-them)

Answer (score 1):

ALLAH is ghafoor and rahem and ALLAH can forgive each and every sin commited by his people but the basic thing is that you should ashamed on your sin deeply by heart and felt sorry to ALLAH that u will not commited that sin again.