# Is it true that Allah forgives all sins except those who expose them?

Tags: sin, forgiveness

I’ve read a lot on the internet that Allah forgives all sins except those who expose them. Is this 100% true?

Answer (score 2):

in islam allah forgives everything except people who Associate partner with Allah,
and about exposing sins, the prophet Mohamed said

> "Every son of Adam sins, and the best of the sinners are the repentant."

and there is another proof in the Quran surat NISA 116

> "Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly gone far astray."

i think this one explains everything about forgiveness i hope that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

It is a true statement based on the following Sahih hadith:

> I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying. **"All the sins of my followers will be forgiven except those of the Mujahirin (those who commit a sin openly or disclose their sins to the people).** An example of such disclosure is that a person commits a sin at night and though Allah screens it from the public, then he comes in the morning, and says, 'O so-and-so, I did such-and-such (evil) deed yesterday,' though he spent his night screened by his Lord (none knowing about his sin) and in the morning he removes Allah's screen from himself." [Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/99)

From the phrasing of the hadith and the numerous other evidences of forgiveness, it can be gathered that it only applies to unrepentant bragging.

To be clear, it does not talk about sins done in public but rather only sins that one brags about.